# Make django url tag fail silently

Tags: django, django-urls, django-templates

The Django {% url %} templatetag raises a NoReverseMatch error when it can't reverse the provided URL. This is useful in development, but in production, this stops the user dead in their tracks with an ugly 500 error, blocking the whole page, and leading them to think our site is broken.

Template developers shouldn't be able to bring down the whole site with a typo.  What I want to do is transparently override this behavior so that, in production only, if a reverse match can't be found, it outputs a default url, like "#", and reports the error to our exception tracking system in the background, but still lets the user continue with what they were doing without raising the 500 error.

Is there a way to replace the default {% url %} tag with my own safer version, transparently? I don't want to have to add a {% load my_custom_url_tag %} at the top of every single template on the site, because at some point people will forget, and the behavior of the tag is will otherwise be the same, the only difference is how it handles errors.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built-in url tag in silent mode, try the lookup, and then use the URL it finds—if it finds something.

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

> This `{% url ... as var %}` syntax will not cause an error if the view is missing. In practice you’ll use this to link to views that are optional:

```
{% url 'path.to.view' as the_url %}
{% if the_url %}
   <a href="{{ the_url }}">Link to optional stuff</a>
{% endif %}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: too bad overriding is not possible, as the code for a solution of your question is quite long!

Answer (score 0):

By implementing your own url tag, you're opening yourself up to lots of forward compatibility issues. My recommendation would be to add custom 500 error handler instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view

I would think you would actually want the view to throw an error if a template developer has made a typo. Trying to mask that behavior seems illogical - isn't that reason enough to have some simple unit tests to make sure your views are at least returning a 200 response code?

Comment: We already have a custom 500 error page that reports NoReverseMatch errors to us. It's going to be tracked either way.  What I dont' want to happen is for the user to be blocked from whatever they were trying to do and complain that the whole site is down, just because some editor put a bad {% url %} tag in a paragraph of copy.  I want it to be just as inconsequential as if someone put in a broken <A HREF> tag in the page.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you would let code that doesn't run into production.

Comment: By that logic any page with a spelling error in the copy should also throw a 500 error.

Comment: Wrong. {% url %} is a Django template tag, not plain text. If you're allowing tags in an input field and then later expect to evaluate them, then you need to be validating the input for proper formatting. In the case of allowing a {% url %} tag, you would have to parse the tag out, call reverse on it and see if it doesn't bomb.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that there are tags in an input field?

Comment: "just because some editor put a bad {% url %} tag in a paragraph of copy"

Comment: When for example using django-cms, you have the app hook pattern. Means, when a page with app hook "search" is not yet created, and the main template uses {% url "search" %}, this will also be a 500.  I like the idea of having a tracking mechanism...otherwise I would just use the `as` variant, as proposed from @jreyes.

Comment: This should definitely fail silently, or as loud as a log error, just because one link is broken on the page doesn't mean the whole website should go down. :)

It is all engineering, if you are Paypal yeah make sure none of your payment links are broken, if you are a casual website it is okay that some links are broken for some data.

Comment: "By implementing your own url tag, you're opening yourself up to lots of forward compatibility issues. " no you are not, you will just call the original function and surround it with try-catch.